# How to fix the program won't show other results

Tags: python

I have the following problem

```
import os
import json
import wmi
from random import choice
import time

filename = "kill.json"
with open(filename) as file:
    kill = json.load(file)

def taskKill(imageNames: list):
    cmdPrefix = 'taskkill /F /IM '
    for imageName in imageNames:
        cmd = cmdPrefix + imageName
        os.system(cmd)


while 1==1:
    c=wmi.WMI()
    def check_process_running(rty):
        if(c.Win32_Process(name=rty)):
            print("Process is running")
            taskKill(kill)
            return
        else:
            print("Process is not running")
    StrA =choice(kill)
    check_process_running(StrA)
```

In this code that detects if the program is open and closes it, no matter how I change it, it always says Process is not running.

Comment: What's the return value of `c.Win32_Process(name=rty)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your script is depending on the line `if(c.Win32_Process(name=rty))` - it seems the return of Win32_Process is always `True`.

- Insert a print statement with the value of `Win32_Process` before this line
- Have you tried to provide the argument as a String ("StrA" instead of StrA)?

To check all current running processes, use:

```
import os, wmi 
c = wmi.WMI() 
for process in c.Win32_Process(name="python.exe"):
    print(process.ProcessId, process.Name) 
print("current processId:", os.getpid())
```